# Perl nested hashes matching and merging

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, reference

I have a file that is read and split into %ojects, the %objects are populated as shown below.

```
$VAR1 = 'cars';
$VAR2 = {
          'car1' => {
                        'info1' => '"fast"',
                        'info2' => 'boring'
                      },
          'car2' => {
                        'info1' => '"slow"',
                        'info2' => 'boring info'
                      },
          'car3' => {
                        'info1' => '"unique"',
                        'info2' => 'useless info'
                      }
                };
$VAR3 = 'age';
$VAR4 = {
          'new' => {
                                  'info3' => 'rust',
                                  'info4' => '"car1"'
                                },
          'old' => {
                                  'info3' => 'shiny',
                                  'info4' => '"car2" "car3"'
                                }
                   }
         };
```

My goal is to insert data like "car1 fast rust, car2 slow shiny, car3 unique shiny" in a DB but I can't get e.g. "rust to match based on info4 in age" ..

```
my $key = cars;
my $key2 = age;

foreach my $obj (keys %{$objects{$key}}) {                          # for every car
    @info1s = $objects{$type}{$obj}{'info1'} =~ m/"(.*?)"/g;        # added to clean up all info1
    foreach my $infos ($info1s) {
        dbh execute insert $obj $infos                              # this gives me "car1 fast, car2 slow, car3 unique"
    } 
...
```

Can somebody please point me in the right direction to fetch and store info4 with related info1/info2?

Thanks!

Comment: How does it relate -- is it because `info4` has value `car1` which is a key in the second hashref `$VAR2`?  Seems like you just need to carefully iterate over these data structures.  Btw, please add which of the shown dumps is which data structure in the code.  There is only one in code (`%objects`) but the dump shows multiple ones.

Comment: Yes, that is how they relate and what I am struggling to figure out how to match. The code example should give a output from VAR1 and VAR2 only as I am struggling to match and retrieve data from the rest. If I continue down the loop-hole (foreach) by adding another $obj2 with $key2 I just end up with a mess of entries like every car will be fast,slow and unique etc..

Comment: Is it always the same labels, `info1` through `info4`, in the second-level hashref?  Or is it merely the two key-value pairs in the bottom (deepest) hashref?

Comment: It is always the same labels so the answer is accepted. Nice trick with Data::Leaf::Walker to get the deepest values. I'll see if I can toy with this to suit the entire thing, awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take the objective to be as follows.
Get values for (`info4`) keys in `$VAR4`, at the deepest-level hashref, and find them as top-level keys in `$VAR2` hashref. Then associate with them both a value from a (`info3`) key, their "sibling" in their own  `$VAR4`'s deepest level hashref, as well as the value of a key (`info1`) from `$VAR2`.

One can traverse the structure by hand for this purpose, specially if it's always with the same two levels as shown, but it's easier and better with libraries. I use [Data::Leaf::Walker](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Leaf::Walker) to get leaves (deepest values) and key-paths to them, and [Data::Diver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Diver) to get values for known paths.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dump;    
use Data::Leaf::Walker;
use Data::Diver qw(Dive);

my $hr1 = {
    'car1' => { 'info1' => 'fast',   'info2' => 'boring' },
    'car2' => { 'info1' => 'slow',   'info2' => 'boring info' },
    'car3' => { 'info1' => 'unique', 'info2' => 'useless info' }
};
my $hr2 = {
    'new' => { 'info3' => 'rust',  'info4' => 'car1' },
    'old' => { 'info3' => 'shiny', 'info4' => 'car2 car3' }
};

my $walker = Data::Leaf::Walker->new($hr2);    
my %res;    
while ( my ($path, $value) = $walker->each ) { 
    next if $path->[-1] ne 'info4';

    # Some "values" have multiple needed values separated by space
    for my $val (split ' ', $value) { 
        # Get from 'info4' path the one to its sibling, 'info3'
        my @sibling_path = ( @{$path}[0..$#$path-1], 'info3' );

        # Collect results: values of `info3` and `info1`
        push @{$res{$val}}, 
            Dive( $hr2, @sibling_path   ), 
            Dive( $hr1, ($val, 'info1') );
    }
}
dd \%res;
```

This assumes a few things and takes some shortcuts, for simplicity.

For one, I use explicit `infoN` keys from the questions, and the two-level structure. If data is, or can be different, this shouldn't be hard to adjust.

Next, this assumes that a value like `car1` always exists as a key in the other hashref.  Add an `exists` check for that key if it is possible that it doesn't exist as a key.

I've removed some extra quotes from data.  (If that's for database entry do that when constructing the statement. If data comes in with such extra quotes it should be easy to adjust the code to take them into account.)

The above program prints

```
{
  car1 => ["rust", "fast"],
  car2 => ["shiny", "slow"],
  car3 => ["shiny", "unique"],
}
```

(I use [Data::Dump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) to display complex data structure, for its simplicity and default compact output.)